# Cannot distinguish (removed) from (removed)

Tags: feature-request, chat, mobile-web

I was on mobile chat today and I accidentally sent a message so I deleted it. Then as a joke the message was followed by a message with the literal text `(removed)`. I suddenly realized I could not tell the difference between a deleted message and a faked one:

[image: hello I am alt text. Have a good day]

Can this be fixed? Perhaps by making the deleted message a slight gray like on the desktop version?

Comment: Looks like poor `.deleted` class was left unattended.

Comment: Mobile chat works for you? Interesting. For me, the bottom part of the page (the type message part) is just cut off :/

Comment: @Zizouz212 that part is cut off when I use the google keyboard (gboard) but is fine when I use default apple keyboard

Comment: I use Safari with the normal keyboards, but I'm assuming that SE thinks my phone screen is bigger. You have an iPhone 5 or 6, right? I'm happy with my iPhone 4 :)